# macro to build Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have created a macro to build a Pivot Table. So far, it gives an error saying that Method CreatePivotTable of object PivotCache failed. The issue is definitely the PRange because when I try to run it with a defined range it runs fine. The defined range that works is below:

```
Set PRange = DSheet.Range(Cells(4, 61), Cells(44, 69))
```

The code I try to run is below:

```
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache1 As PivotCache
Dim PTable1 As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set DSheet = Worksheets("OTD")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 62).End(xlUp).Row

Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(4, 61).Resize(LastRow, 69)
Set PCache1 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
Set PTable1 = PCache1.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=DSheet.Cells(1, 130), TableName:="PivotTable1")

With PTable1
 .CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Customer"

 With .PivotFields("Customer:")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
  .Position = 1
 End With

 With .PivotFields("Customer:")
  .Orientation = xlDataField
  .Position = 1
  .Function = xlCount
 End With

End With
```

Comment: If you debug your code using F8 and check what value variable `LastRow` Holds.

Comment: well if I press F8 it does not do anything

Comment: sorry, I found it.. it says 0

Comment: but the column has values

Comment: 1. Stay in Visual Basic Editor 2. Click anywhere inside your code and press F8. 3. VBE will then immediately highlight the sub you are in. 4. Then step through code by repetitively pressing F8 button until you reach variable and cross it. 5. Hover mouse over or add watch to see the value.

Comment: ok great I did and it says 0. But I dont get it because I actually have data in column 62

Comment: At any rate, it should be at least 1 even if column was empty! I suspect in your code (where it is giving error ) you have uninitialized variable which is having 0 value.

Comment: sorry to ask but what do you mean by uninitialized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157332/discussion-between-shrivallabha-redij-and-pericles-faliagas).